# Django how to export datetime from MySQL to csv as correct format

Tags: mysql, django, datetime, django-views

I can show datetime from mysql by convert datetime of mysql to string like this code.

```
upd_time = str(log.updated)
```

Then, I use javascript to convert to date like this

```
<script>
    const dateFromMysql = '{{ upd_time }}';
    // conver the string into javascript date object
    const dateObject = new Date(dateFromMysql);

    // output complete date in javascript
    document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = dateObject;
</script>
```

It show correct date. I export datetime from mysql to csv with this code.

```
def export_csv(request):

    key=request.POST['key']
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= '+ str(key)+".csv"

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['field1','field2','updated'])

    users = Data.objects.filter(key=key).values_list('field1','field2','updated')
    for user in users:
        writer.writerow(user)

    return response
```

In column updated show the time like this.

[image]

It is UTC timezone. I change **TIME_ZONE** and **USE_TZ** in setting it show same time format in mysql. How to export datetime from csv to local timezone?